# How to I create a folder just like /data in arm Android devices?

Tags: android, linux, android-kernel

I want to create a folder in android arm targets which will be like /data which has has read-write permission?
I followed following steps in init.rc:-

1. mkdir /home 0771 system system
2. chown system system /home
3. chmod 0771 /home

After these commands folder created has following permissions : -

**drwxrwx--x system   system            2012-01-01 00:42 home**

but when I Create folder in it showing error as shown below  : -

[image]

Do I need to add more commands in init.rc to create this folder which will lets me create new folders and files into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create directory in root with read write permissions (steps) : -

1. mkdir /home 0771 system system
2. chown system system /home
3. chmod 0771 /home
4. mount -o remount,rw /home /

Thanks.